# Javascript/jquery AJAX post WITH VARS function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I created this synchronous Ajax function to simply post data:

```
function postme(id, tt) {
 tt['id'] = id;

 $.ajax({
   async:false, type: 'post', url: 'post.php', data: tt,
   success: function(response){ console.log(response);return response; }
 });
}
```

The response is: `{"Info": "aoaaa"}`

The `console.log(response);` provides the JSON in the console, but the return gives a 'undefined'. I tried calling it like this:

```
postme('generate', {'1':'ee','w':'yy'});
```

I tried JSON parse, giving the function a name I tried everything I could found online but it just does not work.

I've looked at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but that does not seem to work for me since the function does not send variables like mine, it will just do `foo();` or `postme();` in my case. How do I do this with vars?

Edit: I do not NEED to use async, if there is a better code to not use it, I would rather use it.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is not a duplicate please read my question.

Comment: Oh geez.  You're doing synchronous Ajax.  That's horrible.  I will unmark as a dup, but that's your first problem.  Stop using synchronous Ajax.  That's horrible for the user experience.

Comment: Can you really read code that is only indented one space per indent?  I sure can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, stop using synchronous Ajax.  That's horrible for the user experience and should pretty much NEVER be used.

But, if you are using synchronous Ajax, your problem is that there is no return value from `postme()`.  You are returning inside the `success` handler, but that just goes back into the ajax infrastructure, not back to the caller of `postme()`.  Instead, you can simply do this:

```
function postme(id, tt) {
    tt['id'] = id;
    var retVal;

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: tt,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            retVal = response;
        }
    });
    return retVal;
}
```

---

What you really should do is use asynchronous ajax like this:

```
function postme(id, tt) {
    tt['id'] = id;

    return $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: tt
    });
}

postme(...).then(function(response) {
    // process response here
}, function (err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Edit: I do not NEED to use async, if there is a better code to not use it, I would rather use it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that synchronous AJAX should be avoided, but if you must this should work:

```
function postme(id, tt) {
 var r = null;
 tt['id'] = id;

 $.ajax({
   async:false, type: 'post', url: 'post.php', data: tt,
   success: function(response){ console.log(response);r =response; }
 });

 return r;
}
```

Comment: Edit: I do not NEED to use async, if there is a better code to not use it, I would rather use it.

Comment: If you don't need synchronous AJAX then it is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. The jfriend00 answer above has a good example of how to do this with async.

Comment: note that browsers have deprecated `async:false` and now warn of deprection in console when it is used

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the return value is used in some function, such as:

```
function foo(response) { /* some code */}
```

then provide foo as callback.

```
function postme(id, tt, callback) {
 tt['id'] = id;

 $.ajax({
   type: 'post', url: 'post.php', data: tt,
   success: callback
 });
}
```

and you call the function 'postme' as:

```
postme(param1, param2, foo)
```